# Oscillation of a converging sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a measurable set. Suppose that a sequence $(f_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of continuous functions $f_{n}\colon E\to\mathbb{R}$ converges in the space $L^{1}(E)$ to a continuous function $f$. I want to prove that $\operatorname{osc}(f,E)\le\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}\operatorname{osc}(f_{n},E)$, where $\operatorname{osc}(\varphi,E):=\sup\limits_{x,y\in E}|\varphi(x)-\varphi(y)|$ for $\varphi\colon E\to\mathbb{R}$.

I suspect that this somehow follows from the fact that convergence in $L^{1}(E)$ implies the existence of a subsequence $(f_{n_{k}})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $f_{n_{k}}(x)\to f(x)$ as $k\to\infty$ for almost all $x\in E$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $osc(f,E) >\lim \inf osc(f_n,E)$ Then there a susbequnece $n_k$ and a number $r$ such that  such that $osc(F,E) >r>osc (f_{n_k},E)$ for all $k$. By $L^{1}$ convergence we can extract a further subsequence $(f_{n_{k_i}})$ which converes a.e to $f$. If $x,y \in E$ then $r >|f_{n_{k_i}}(x)-f_{n_{k_i}}(y)|$ and letting $i \to \infty$ we get $r \geq |f(x)-f(y)|$ provided $x$ and $y$ do not belong to the exceptional set where the subsequence does not converge to $f$. But $f$ is continuous so we get $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq r <osc (f,E)$ for all $x,y$. This is a contradiction.